# WatchKit becomeCurrentPage() page-based

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

WatchKit becomeCurrentPage() in a page-based hiearchy does not work when swiping to a specific page, then pressing a button that uses NSNotificationCenter to send a postNotification which calls becomeCurrentPage(). This is all done in the main thread.

first InterfaceController:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showPage", object: self, userInfo: ["test": test])
}
```

Another InterfaceController:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showThisPage:", name: "showPage", object: nil)

func showThisPage(notification: NSNotification) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.becomeCurrentPage()
    }
}
```

Comment: The code example appears to make no sense. When a page is the current page, it displays a button, and tapping that button tries to make the current page into the current page, by loading it as the current page? And at least as importantly, why would you try and use a notification to make the page the current page? Finally, when you say it does not work, you need to describe what you are actually seeing and what you expected to see.

Comment: The function showThisPage is in another InterfaceController. I didn't make that clear sorry.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?  I am trying to do something similar.

Comment: No, I ended up using notifications combined with becomeCurrentPage(). I don't know if there is something new though.